# Webpack can't resolve svg

Tags: javascript, webpack

Webpack can't resolve svg when I try to use my svg as a background with relative path

```
image background-image: url('./checkmark.svg');
```

webpack give me 'can't resolve' error

But absolute path is ok.

```
background-image: url(C:\Users\leo\Desktop\project\hotel\src\components\checkbox-list\__menu\checkbox-list__checkbox\checkmark.svg);
```

Actualy my config rules:

```
module: {
  rules: [{
      test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
      type: 'asset/resource',
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/,
      type: 'asset',
    },
    {
      test: /\.pug$/,
      loader: 'pug-loader',
      options: {
        pretty: true,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

Answer (score 4):

i think you need to use [url_loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) within webpack to load svgs the same way you loading scss . and then import it in your code and use it in your component or file .

`npm i svg-url-loader --save-dev`

```
{
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

#### vue example [srouce](https://github.com/Developmint/nuxt-svg-loader/issues/30)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <InlineSVG />
    <div class="external-svg" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import InlineSVG from './public/inline.svg';

export {
  components: {
    InlineSVG,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.external-svg {
  background-image: url("./public/external.svg"); 
}
</style>
```

#### workaround no loader

if you are using it into css directly and then css loaded using webpack than bare in mind that the link should be working in dist too , so you can provide the file manually in dist with the same link as in src

Comment: I already have 'asset/resource' in config https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/
Actualy problem solved, I create svg folder in src folder and background-image: url('/src/checkmark.svg'); is work